# How to pivot a category-column to individual columns per category

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have been playing with this Rubix-cube of a power query problem for long enough and concede defeat.

I have a table with values which look like this:

```
Category | Date     | Lead Ref | Values
---------+----------+----------+---------
Cat A    | Jan 2020 | 1234A    | 11,111
Cat B    | Jan 2020 | 1234A    | TextOne
Cat C    | Jan 2020 | 1234A    | 33
```

But I want to pivot the Category column so it creates two additional columns and takes the corresponding Values with it. For example:

```
Date     | Lead Ref | Cat A   | Cat B   | Cat C
---------+----------+---------+---------+-------
Jan 2020 | 1234A    | 11,111  | TextOne | 33
```

Any help appreciated!

Thanks

Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Category", type text}, {"Date", type date}, {"Lead Ref", type text}, {"Values", type text}}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Changed Type", List.Distinct(#"Changed Type"[Category]), "Category", "Values")
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```

[image]